# Installshield wizard Path contains invalid character in vs 2012 deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield

Am trying to Deploy my visual studio 2012 vc++ application through Install Shield wizard.
The error am getting is :
Error 1324. The path .. contains an invalid character

I followed this tutorial and got succeed with a sample application .

http://www.flexerasoftware.com/webdocuments/productdemos/IS2010_VSLE_Demo/IS2010_VSLE_Demo-lite.html

But when i try to deploy my application, the setup file which i created is giving me this error.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this one before in the wild but it's described at:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292582

Basically it sounds like the computer has invalid data in the registry for one of the built in directories that Windows Installer resolves.  It's an environmental issue rather then installer logic issue.

I'd have to see the installer log and computer registry to confirm or deny that though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently (with Installshield 2015). The problem was, that under *Application Data/Files and Folders* there was a definition for a folder called *..* - so the setup would try to create a folder *..* on the target system, which of course doesn't work.

Deleting that folder definition and moving its contained files to the parent folder definition fixed the problem for me.